# Singular/Plural URL Structure in WordPress for Post Types

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I am working on a client's website, and he has asked me a very genuine question, and I am unable to figure it out.

He is Creating a Website for Piano Chords, where he will write tutorials about chords in general and each individual chords too. And he wants them to be of a similar post type.

So I registered a CPT `Chords` with the slug `chords` using the documentation on [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Now the problem is the site has multiple posts about chords. And they will be of 2 kinds.

One will be generic to all chords, hence the word needed in the slug is `chords` and not the singular form.

e.g. -> https://mypianonotes.com/chords/overview/

This is fine. Now problem is when we need content like "C Major Chord". This is supposed to be singular. So the slug/url should be `chord/c-major/` and not `chords/c-major/`.

Is there any solution to this problem? Or will I have to create 2 separate post types?

Answer (score 0):

Register the post type as 'my_chords' then add a rewrite rule parameter in the arguments like this

```
<?php
$args = array(
 'rewrite' => array('with_front'=>false, 'slug'=>'chord'),
);

register_post_type( 'my_chords', $args );

?>
```

Then create a page for 'chords' with a child page of 'overview'.

Hope this helps :)